# how to merge rows with similar index pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, grouping

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
customer           sales      gm%

TRC NL              3000      20
trc slgm            2000      30
TRC gmbh D          1000      40
Dinamic reg         300       10
dinamic             400       15
DINAMIC kgs italy   400       20
```

I would like to combine the rows with the same company and calculate sum for sales and a weighted mean for gm% and obtain something like this:

```
customer           sales      gm%

TRC                6000       30
Dinamic            1200       15
```

I tried using pd.concat but with not similar indexes doesn´t work.

Comment: The `sales` column in the output you want is given by a sum ? Because I don't find the same result as yours.

Comment: yes, sorry i made a mistake while typing. i just corrected it.

Comment: Ok I see. Did the answer solved your problem ?

Comment: hi, yes it helped, but i just noticed that there are some customer names that need at least 2 words, otherwise is difficult to find them.For example as result I get some "SA" when I would need "SA NESSET"

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

First, transform the `customer` column by extracting the first part of the name, in order to have a common key between the multiple variants of the customer names:

```
df["customer"] = df["customer"].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0].upper())
df.head()
```

Then do a groupby:

```
df.groupby("customer").agg({"sales":"sum", "gm%":"mean"})
```

Output:

```
           sales    gm%
customer        
DINAMIC     1200     15
TRC         6000     30
```